# .post() working but Not Completed in jquery .click() method

Tags: jquery, post, tracking

Hi everyone i write code for tracking user click on links and record them on php pages. Thi is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tracking outgoing links with JavaScript and PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><a href="test2.html">Test link to Google</a></p>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
    $.post("get.php", { name: "John" }      
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is working, the page get.php is requseted but not completed. So the data cannot be saved. it seems page move too quick

How to solve this problems. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating away might abort the AJAX request before it was fully sent. To avoid this, do not load the target page before the request has finished:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post("get.php", { name: "John" }, function() {
        location.href = url;
    });
});
```

However, middle-clicking a link will not trigger this event. If you *always* want to fire your event, use a `mousedown` event and check `e.which`. If it's `1` it was the left button and you need to `e.preventDefault()` and redirect after the AJAX request finished. If it's `2` it was the middle button and you only need to send the AJAX request and not do anything else - the page will open in a new tab anyway.

```
$('a').on('click mousedown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == '3') {
        return; /* do not handle rightclick */
    }
    else if(e.type == 'click' || e.which == '1') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post("get.php", { name: "John" }, function() {
        if(e.type == 'click' || e.which == '1') {
            location.href = url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it possible to run only for external links?

Comment: Right now it works on all links. To restrict it to external links, use `$('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"], a[href^="//"]')` instead of `$('a')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $.post("get.php", { name: "John" }, 
                                      ^ why this comma     
    });
```

you should do something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  var self = $(this);
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the navigation of `a`
  $.post("get.php", { name: "John" },function() {
        location.href = self.attr('href');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var shouldFollowAnchor = false;

        $.ajaxSetup.async = false;

        $.post("get.php", { name: "John" }, function () {
            shouldFollowAnchor = true;
        });

        return shouldFollowAnchor;
    });
});
```

The reason for jumping to the page is beacuse when you click on the link, the data is posted AND you navigate to the link in the href attribute of the anchor element.
You stop following that link by returning false.
This example the script waits for the response from the server - yea, you can add some validations if you like -, meantime you can display some "loading..." or sending "sending..." messages, users will like to know what's happening. =)